# CSS Require Order - Asset Pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have an app rendering a view called `feeds` and it comes with it's own styling called `feeds.scss`. The view uses a layout called `default_app.scss`.

The controller action has `render layout: 'default_app'`.
In the `default_app.html.erb`, `= stylesheet_link_tag 'default_app', params[:controller]`, which indicates the layout stylesheet should be required first.

The issue here is that within `default_app.scss`, I define a set of constant colors such as: `$red: #aaa` but when I use `$red` within `feeds.scss`, it's undefined. This doesn't make sense because shouldn't the layout styling be required prior to the page(view specific css)?

```
app
- assets
  - stylesheets
    - newsfeeds
      - feeds.scss (want to use colors here)
  - default_app.scss (defined colors here)
- controllers
  - newsfeeds_controller.rb
- views
  - newsfeeds
    - feeds.html.haml
  - layouts
    - default_app.html.haml (= stylesheet_link_tag 'default_app', params[:controller])
```

Comment: can you show the actual code and files that you're requiring where?

Comment: Edited with the directory. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Scss variables are replaced before the actual stylesheet tags are used when compiling them, you have to extract configuration to another file and include it on every .scss that uses variables

Comment: @arieljuod Are you saying that the best thing to do here is to have a `colors.scss` file containing the constants and just requiring it on every spreadsheet that needs it?

Comment: Yes, variables are replaced at compile time, it doesn't matter the order you put them in the stylesheet tag, the variable is needed way before that. You have to tell every .scss that needs a variable to read that variable somewhere. In my project I have a _configuration.scss file with all the variables and every .scss file that needs them has an @import "configuration"; at the beginning.

Comment: i've added an answer with a little explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scss variables are processed at compile time, the order you use them doesn't actually matter for variables since, by the time the code links to the .css file, the variables were already replaces by the scss compiler on the assets pipeline, feeds.css.scss doesn't know what $red means since it's defined in another file.

You have to include the variables on every .scss file that uses them.

_colors.css.scss

```
$red: #ff0000;
$blue: #0000ff;
$gree: #00ff00;
```

default_app.css.scss

```
@import('colors');
.something {
  color: $red;
}
```

feeds.css.scss

```
@import('colors');
.other_thing {
  color: $red;
  background: $blue;
}
```

Comment: In another working implementation, I defined the colors in `application.scss` and then I imported the stylesheet that needed to use the colors with `@import('newsfeeds/feeds)` in `application.scss`. Is this because I am specifically importing the stylesheet after the colors were already defined above the import?

Comment: If you import feeds.css.scss inside application.css.scss, then you don't need to add feeds.css on the stylesheet tag, since the content of feeds will end up inside application.css after compilation (or you will have the same css twice, once inside application.css and once inside feeds.css). And yes, it worked because you imported feeds after the declaration of $red.

Comment: anyway, it's also a good practice to move variables outside the main css files, better for maintainability and flexibility

Answer (score 0):

Here's my first shot at it.
I am not sure what you're doing with the `params[:controller]`. The `stylesheet_link_tag` takes sources as an argument, see here
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag

This would be a default setup - `stylesheet_link_tag "style", media: "all"`

If you are looking for controller specific example - see the example here
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

"You can also opt to include controller specific stylesheets and JavaScript files only in their respective controllers using the following:"

```
<%= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %> or <%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller] %>
```

Give section 2.4 (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) a read where you are handling your main layout css through `application.css` . This should point you in the right direction. It's likely due to how you're requiring files. If you're still stuck, feel free to show how you're requiring files

Comment: With the `params[:controller]`, I _opt to include controller specific stylesheets only in their respective controllers_ (from the docs). The `stylesheet_link_tag` is the only place where I require my stylesheets, but I put it in the order of `default_app` and _then_  `params[:controller]`, so I expect the constants in `default_app.scss` to be defined for usage in `params[:controller]` stylesheets. That isnt the case here so I'm wondering if the two different stylesheets are being required at the same time instead of linearly.